# Quality of two norm solution in basis pursuit

Tags: matrices, optimization

Suppose I want to solve

$$\min\; \|x\|_0$$
$$\text{st}\; Mx=b$$

with solution $x^*$.
What are the known error bounds between $x^*$ and the min two norm solution $\hat x= \arg\min_x\{\|x\|_2: Mx=b\}$? Are there any obvious ones?

Thank you!

Comment: The min two norm solution can be very, very bad.  I'm not aware of any positive results.  There are results for one norm minimization of course.

Comment: So what if I add some assumptions on $M$, like we have at least xx samples, we have RIP, etc? Actually if you can point me to the negative results that also would be very helpful! thank you!